# PHP - echoing class properties that are protected

Tags: php

For a data structure like this:

`Google_Maps_Bounds Object [min_lon:protected] => -124.15252917 [min_lat:protected] => 36.39249130`

How do you echo out the protected variables?

The following usual way doesn't seem to work:

`echo $obj->'min_lon:protected' ;`

yielding error:

`'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' '`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for the class you are using. It should have some *method* you can call to get the desired data, e.g. `getMinLon()` or something to that effect. You cannot directly access `protected` variables, that's what they're `protected` for.